# tomcat sign in tomcat start page

Tags: tomcat, tomcat10

I have the following lines in tomcat-users.xml,but tomcat doesn't allow me to sign in.

role rolename="admin-gui"
user username="joe" password="jungle13" roles="manager-gui,admin-gui"

I tried to sign in to tomcat admin-gui with the above user name (joe).
I want log into admin page.

Comment: What Tomcat version?

Comment: tomcat version 10.0.27

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You got the role name wrong. Try 'manager-gui' instead of 'admin-gui'.

See [Configuring Manager Application Access](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-10.1-doc/manager-howto.html#Configuring_Manager_Application_Access) in the official Tomcat docs for more details.

Comment: I did it. Still it doesn't work. I get 401 unauthorized error.

Comment: Note that, in the tomcat-users.xml shipped with Tomcat, the example roles and users near the bottom of the file are commented out. Perhaps you added your 'joe' user to that comment?

Comment: I removed tomcat completely from the system, and reinstalled. Added the user into tomcat-users.xml. Now it works. Some thing must have gone wrong during the first installation. Thanks for your help.